# Faithful representation of group of order $p^4$

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, p-groups, modular-representation-theory

In the (xi) group of the classification of groups of order $p^4$ given by W.Burnside in his book, *"Theory of groups of finite order"*. The group ($\mathbb{Z}_{p^{2}}\rtimes \mathbb{Z}_{p^{}}) \rtimes_{\phi}\mathbb{Z}_{p^{}} $, have presentation
$$\langle a,b,c : a^{p^{2}}=b^p=c^p=e,\,ab=ba^{1+p},\,ac=cab,\,bc=cb\rangle$$

I was trying to explore about the representation (must be faithful) of the above group in $\mathrm{GL}(4,F_p)$, i.e. group of $4\times 4$ invertible matrices, taken over $F_p$.  Please guide me in the right direction, from where to start or if my statement mathematically correct or not ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One small remark: if $p > 4$ then any element $x$ of ${\rm GL}(4,F_{p})$ of order a power of $p$ satisfies $(x-I)^{4} = 0$, so that we certainly have $(x-I)^{p} = 0$ and $x^{p} = I$.
Hence ${\rm GL}(4,F_{p})$ contains no element of order $p^{2}$ when the prime $p$ is greater than $3$.

Comment: Kindly explain me how to get this result ? and the above result is true for $p>3$ or $4$

Comment: The explanation is given by linear algebra, as shown, except I just notcied a small typo, which I will correct now.. Also, since $p$ is a prime, the requirement that  $p>3$ certainly forces $p \geq 5$, so $p > 4.$

Comment: I am sorry but I am not able to see the fact that if $x$ is any $p$-element of $GL(4,F_p)$, then it will satisfy ${(x-I)}^4=0$. Can you please elaborate a bit more ?

Comment: Let us suppose that $x$ has order $p^{k}$. Then $x^{p^{k}} = I$, so we have $(x-I)^{p^{k}} = 0$ because $F_{p}$ has characteristic $p$. Hence $1$ is the only root of the characteristic polynomial of  $x$. By the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem, we must have $(x-I)^{4} = 0.$